# Visualizing Vector Tiles map in 3D

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, 3d, vector-tiles, 3d-map

As I am using QGIS not for a long time I am asking myself whether there is a possibility to visualize a Vector Tiles map resource in 3D in QGIS. In comparison to common shape files there isn't an attribute table accessible filled with data that could be used for that reason.

The resource: https://basemap.de/web-vektor/

[https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_de_3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_de_3857/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)

The vector resource contains elevation data that is also shown in QGIS but I cannot use that data to extrude objects.

[image]

Comment: Is there some elevation information within your vector data source ? Otherwise you need to setup a 3d view in QGIS with elevation coming from a relevant source

Comment: Yes, the vector data source contains elevation data. QGIS also shows exactly that data if you click on a certain object in the map, e. g. a building. QGIS only does not allow reading out that data automatically and using it to extrude objects. Exactly this is possible with .shp-files and works fine.

In layer properties there also is not a rider to select "height" or something like that like I am used to it.

Comment: I don't know enough to provide you with a solution. You may want to update your question to clarify what you need. To start with, I thought you wanted a 3D rendering based on a terrain height layer. But as far as I understand, you want to extrude vector geometries in 3D, based on the "hoehe" property (height in meters)

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, the last thing you wrote is exactly what I want to do: Extruding vector geometries in 3D, based on the "hoehe" property by using the given Vector Tiles resource. Sorry for my imprecise question.